# Return new class that inherited some class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

I am making my custom CharacterStatusfunctionManagement. 
There are CharacterStatusFunction and inherited class like
Strength, Defend,  Burn, and others.

```
public class CharacterStatusFunction : IComparable<CharacterStatusFunction> {
      //Something
 }

 public class Strength : CharacterStatusFunction {
 }
```

I Load All inherited class in CharacterStatusfunctionManage

```
static Dictionary<string, CharacterStatusFunction> _CharacterStatusFuncDic = new Dictionary<string, CharacterStatusFunction> ();
 static List<string> _CharacterStatusFuncKeyLists = new List<string> ();

[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]
 public static void InItDictionary () {
  List<CharacterStatusFunction> ChrStatusFunctionLists = ReflectiveEnumerator.GetEnumerableOfType<CharacterStatusFunction> ().ToList ();
  for (int i = 0; i < ChrStatusFunctionLists.Count; i++) {
     _CharacterStatusFuncDic.Add (ChrStatusFunctionLists[i].ToString (), ChrStatusFunctionLists[i]);
  }
  Added = true;
  }
```

And I want to get New CharacterStatusManagement by my objectslug like this.

```
public static CharacterStatusFunction GetCharacterStatusFunctionByKey (string key) {
 if(key == "Strength")
 return new Strength{}
 //something else
 }
```

Here is a problem : I want to get 'new' class that inherited characterstatusfunction class, but I can't find the way.
I know there is a way to deepcopy using serialize, but because I'm not copying the values, I think it is not appropriate.

```
 public static CharacterStatusFunction GetCharacterStatusFunctionByKey (string key) {
  if (_CharacterStatusFuncDic.ContainsKey (key)) {
     //This Line Help 
     return new typeof(_CharacterStatusFuncDic[key]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Maybe `return (CharacterStatusFunction)Activator.CreateInstance(_CharacterStatusFuncDic[key].GetType()));`?

Comment: Why not using generic: public static T GetCharacterStatusFunctionByKey<T>() where T : CharacterStatusFunction, new ()  {  return new T(); }

Comment: @Everts Because I can't use  return GetCharacterStatusFunctionByKey<_CharacterStatusFuncDic[key]>();

Comment: @RonBeyer It worked, really thanks!